# Decrypt PHP crypt() function without salt

Tags: php, crypt

I have a small problem. In fact, I have a string crypted with the PHP function `crypt()`, with only one parameter (without the salt parameter).
I would like to know if it is possible to decrypt the password if it was crypted that way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161157/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-a-crypt-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is impossible, because simply [crypt()](http://php.net/crypt) is a One-way string hashing.

You can, however, use brute force but it will be too bad if the password is lengthly...

Answer (score 0):

Function crypt() uses a one-way algorithm, there is no decrypt function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, crypt returns the digest of a hash algorithm which by design can't be reversed. Whether or not you posses the salt is irrelevant in this case.

You can try online Rainbow Tables like those at [CrackStation](https://crackstation.net/) to possibly look the hash up. Your only other alternative is to brute force the hash.